# a tilda in a URL

Tags: asp.net, regex, http, url

Q:
The first time i see an URL contains (~) ,i imagined ..
what the (~) may point to in a real URL??

Comment: What does this specifically have to do with ASP.NET or regular expressions?

Comment: Can you show us the URL?

Comment: Did you really see ~ in URL ? Because ~ combined with some keywords are used as tokens in sharepoint Url ...

Comment: @BoltClock:to clarify that i'm from .net background, and regex, because this what tell me about this

Comment: yeah i remember i see it in universities , i wanna to know what is the point , or the reason?

Comment: @just_name: Could you provide some example URLs? It helps to reduce the amount of guesswork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ~ symbol is perhaps most commonly used by Apache's [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html).  It allows local users on the same machine running the web server to expose a subdirectory of their home directory to the web via Apache.  For example, given the URL `http://www.example.com/~joeuser`, an Apache server might look up joeuser's home directory (usually `/home/joeuser`) and append another path component to it (usually `public_html`, resulting in the path `/home/joeuser/public_html`).  This directory will then map to the `/~joeuser` URI.

It's become common to use URIs like this in more modern MVC-based web applications to refer to a user's profile.  For example, `/~joeuser` might display the profile of the `joeuser` user in some web application.  The meaning comes from the Apache-style URIs -- you are going to that user's "home page," whatever that might be.

Comment: +1 although I think it's actually become less common to use tildes in profile URLs :)

Comment: @BoltClock: It's not pervasive at all, but I've seen quite a few MVC apps doing this lately.  See, for example, [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/~cdhowie).

Answer (score 9):

Since you tagged this [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net):

In certain ASP.NET URLs, for instance the `NavigateUrl` property of some web controls, the tilde represents the root directory of your ASP.NET web application. The following `HyperLink` control points to the root `Default.aspx` page of an ASP.NET site.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a real URL ~ is just like any other letter.

In some programming and in Unix shells ~ means "home directory". ~/ could reference the root directory of the website or the home directory of current user.

Specify more details, possibly with a sample, if you need more info. :)